# Trapz integration of grouped data for certain range

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a DataFrame list as below:

```
Device   TimeSec  Current
  1        0.1      0.02
  1        0.25     0.05
  1        0.32     0.07
  1        0.45     0.01
  1        0.67     0.05
  1        1.01     0.08
  1        1.12     0.11
  1        1.32     0.15
  2        0.11     0.04
  2        0.22     0.06
  2        0.28     0.07
  2        0.35     0.02
  2        0.41     0.05
  2        0.51     0.08
  2        0.61     0.12
 ....
```

1. In each device set of data, there is a current minimum
2. I would like to groupby the DataFrame by "Device" and do trapz integration
3. The integration should be from the beginning of TimeSec of each "Device" data to the "Current" minimum

Previously I asked similar question, I got helped and figured out how to groupby the data by "Device" and trapz integrate for each "Device" group. 
The code for the whole "Device" data integration is:

```
DeviceGroup = df.groupby('Device')
Result = DeviceGroup.apply(lambda x: integrate.trapz(x.Current, x=x.TimeSec))
```

This time I need to integrate from 1st TimeSec data to the "Current" minimum data. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: I expect to have series of integration data. The index of the series would be Device and the column would be the integration value.

Comment: Can you tell me how do you define "current" minimum? Is it per TimeSec or per device group?

Comment: It is the "current" minimum per device group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to filter your dataframe down to values that happen up to minimum value.

```
from scipy import integrate

df[df.groupby('Device')['Current'].transform(lambda x: x.diff().shift().bfill().gt(0).cumprod().astype(bool))]\
  .groupby('Device').apply(lambda g: integrate.trapz(g['Current'], x=g.TimeSec))
```